# Can't import my modules which are in PATH and PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, shell, path, pythonpath

I am trying to import my own python script from another python script. Since i would import the first script quite frequently, i have decided to put the script in ~/lib and added ~/lib to PATH and PYTHONPATH variables. When i run my other script i get ModuleNotFound error

`echo $PATH` yields

`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/home/baran/bin:/home/baran/.local/bin:/home/baran/bin:/home/baran/.local/bin:/home/baran/lib`

`echo $PYTHONPATH` yields

`:/home/baran/lib/`

My ~/lib  folder ( `ls -l ~/lib`)

```
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 baran baran 880 Dec 14 22:33 bbox.py
```

My import

`from bbox import BBox`

My `.bashrc`

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/lib
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$HOME/lib/
```

EDIT: SOLVED!

Changed my My `.bashrc`

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/lib
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$HOME/lib
```

Comment: Is `lib` contained in `import sys; print(sys.path)` ? If yes, create an empty `__init__.py` file into `lib`.

Comment: No, i can't see lib in sys.path. But i now realize python doesn't see PYTHONPATH. It is not in ```os.environ```. When i call it like ```PYTHONPATH="/home/baran/lib" python```, ```lib``` is in ```sys.path``` and finds imports ```bbox```. I guess my problem is with my ```.bashrc``` file.

Comment: Solved! I changed my ```.bashrc``` to ```export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/lib

export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$HOME/lib
```